# Error building ClickOnce application in TFS with Certificate

Tags: tfs, build, certificate, ms-release-management

I have a ClickOnce application that is run through TFS and Release Management for build. I have got it building fine until I introduce a Signing Certificate to the application. The certificate works fine with publishing the application but just wont have anything to do with the Build:

[image]

It is suggested that I try importing the certificate again or import it manually into the current users personal certificate store. I have tried the first but not sure how I go about doing the second.

Has anyone else encountered this problem and overcome it? I am seeing instances of this error on the web but not yet come across one where a build was being carried out on TFS/RM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather simple answer that will teach me to read the error messages a bit more clearly. I just had to install the certificate on the machine running TFS under the user that is used by TFS... All good then!